# How is Bootabiiity Restored to an SD Card (Ubuntu-MATE / Raspberry Pi 4B)?

Tags: boot, partitioning, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate, disk-image

How is Bootability Restored (Repaired) to an SD Card; Raspberry Pi 4B, Ubuntu-Mate 20.04

I don't want to lose my files or customizations.

The SD card for my Raspberry Pi 4B became un-bootable after having been well
customized and with lots of important files and with programs compiled from
source, etc.  It does not fully boot, but does take me to a command-line
interface.  From there I can type 'help', but the commands listed there are
like 'cd/break/pwd/echo/set', etc.  If I do an 'exit' from there, I am pretty well
stuck - inoperable.

The command line error(s) includes the statement(s) - Kernel panic, Exit code = 0x00000100.

I managed to recover important files, including **.bash_aliases** and even FireFox bookmarks, but I would still like to use the SD card as it was.

I am running Ubuntu-MATE 20.04.  The 'gnome-disks' command reports that the 'filesystem system-boot needs repairing'.

So how do I repair it?

Is it possible to use restore bootability to the SD card by re-imaging just
the boot partition, perhaps with the 'dd' command?  and to what extent would
I lose customizations by modifying only the boot partition?

Looking through answers, I also see:

`sudo ddrescue -D --force ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img /dev/sdx`

and I notice that 'ddrescue' is now 'gddrescue'.

Based on the following 'lsblk-p', should I try:

`sudo gddrescue -D --force ubuntu-mate-20.04.1-desktop-arm64+raspi.img /dev/sda1`

/dev/sda is the damaged SD card

```
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
/dev/loop0         7:0    0 48.9M  1 loop /snap/core18/1990
/dev/loop1         7:1    0 48.9M  1 loop /snap/core18/2002
/dev/loop2         7:2    0   28M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11408
/dev/loop3         7:3    0   27M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11043
/dev/loop4         7:4    0   16K  1 loop /snap/software-boutique/56
/dev/loop5         7:5    0    8K  1 loop /snap/ubuntu-mate-pi/11
/dev/loop6         7:6    0 15.2M  1 loop /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/
/dev/loop7         7:7    0 14.9M  1 loop /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/
/dev/sda           8:0    1 58.3G  0 disk 
├─/dev/sda1        8:1    1  255M  0 part 
└─/dev/sda2        8:2    1   58G  0 part 
/dev/mmcblk0     179:0    0 58.3G  0 disk 
├─/dev/mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  255M  0 part /boot/firmware
└─/dev/mmcblk0p2 179:2    0   58G  0 part /
```

Or, so, how do I re-image just 'sda1' partition on the damaged SD card and resume as before?  Is that possible?

Comment: `/dev/sda` is usually an actual *disk* and not an SD card.  Are you sure that's actually an SD card?  If the SD card is showing as a hard drive then it's likely busted and not going to be recoverable.

Comment: I don't know other systems, but ```/dev/sda``` is how I always see it on mine.  A newly inserted card shows up like ```/dev/sda```, and another as ```/dev/sdb```.  An external hard drive, though may be different.  I use one on occasion, but I don't recall how it is identified.

Comment: `lsblk -e 7 -o UUID,NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,MODEL` Like this, you can ask `lsblk` to print even the `MODEL` of the detected hardware. It should help to better determine which entry is which. The `-e 7` argument will narrow the list down to only the physical devices (and leaves away the /dev/loop's).

Comment: Thank you.  I am not wondering which device represents the SD card.  It is **/dev/sda**.
I want to know how to make the partition bootable again and restore functionality.